# How to reorder DOM elements with CSS only?

Tags: html, dom, responsive-design, css-position, flexbox

I have a task to build CSS mobile version for a website, but I am not allowed to change their HTML.

So, there are two `div` elements on the page: `box-1` and `box-2`. Is there any regular way to switch their places, i.e. to move box-2 from bottom to the top, only with CSS?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="box-1"></div>

    <div id="box-2"></div>

</div>
```

And, here is CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width:400px;
}

#box-1 {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}

#box-2 {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: why not change their html order ?

Comment: Because I am working CSS for mobile version, I am not allowed to change HTML.

Comment: Can someone please explain me what is the reason for downvote this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/5C6KG/1/)**

css only solution

```
#wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* optional */
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
#wrapper #box-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #faa;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
#wrapper #box-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #aaa;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use :

```
#box-2{
position:fixed;
margin-top:0px;
}
#box-1{
postion:fixed;
margin-top:;//height of your box-2 div
}
```

By using it you can position your divs wherever you want.
thank You...

Comment: Thanks, but I can not use position:fixed because I don't have fixed height of divs.